# Strange error in Xcode 4.6 refers to subversion

Tags: xcode, svn

The error look like:

```
subversion/libsvn_wc/revision_status.c:64: (apr_err=155036)
subversion/libsvn_wc/wc_db.c:12132: (apr_err=155036)
subversion/libsvn_wc/wc_db_wcroot.c:573: (apr_err=155036)
subversion/libsvn_wc/wc_db_wcroot.c:301: (apr_err=155036)
subversion/libsvn_wc/upgrade.c:1551: (apr_err=155036)
svn: E155036: Working copy '/Volumes/(some path)' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
output of svnversion -n is: 
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

I can nevertheless compile and execute/debug my project but must somewhere get rid of this error ... Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I now it: close Xcode, get "svn upgrade" in the console for each project - ready!
The reason for this error is Xcode 4.x cannot deal with svn 1.7!